# Table is not centered

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx

I'm having some problems creating the following table:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X}
    \textbf{Advantages} & \textbf{Disadvantages}    \\
    \begin{itemize}
        \item  Very efficient!
        \item Use of mild conditions
        \item Broad spectrum of reactions, almost everything
        \item Not Bound to Natural decision!
    \end{itemize}
    & 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Only one enantiomeric form 
        \item Restricted conditions
        \item Prone to inhibition
        \item Better in water
    \end{itemize} 
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

**Problems**

I'd like to center it (now it is more on the left side).

Also, I'd like to center the column titles (advantages & disadvantages).

**What I tried**

I tried using \begin{center} instead of the table environment and I also tried to use \centering command but it didn't work.

How can I do it in a simple manner?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}\centering
    \textbf{Advantages} 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item  Very efficient!
        \item Use of mild conditions
        \item Broad spectrum of reactions, almost everything
        \item Not Bound to Natural decision!
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}\centering
\textbf{Disadvantages}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Only one enantiomeric form 
        \item Restricted conditions
        \item Prone to inhibition
        \item Better in water
    \end{itemize} 
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! simple and effective :)